# How to replace _A_&_B_ using gsub in R

Tags: gsub

I am trying to join two columns containing company names from two distinct data tables on R. In one column I have the pattern `_A_&_B_` where A and B can be any letters. I would like to get rid of those two letters i.e letter of length 1 surrounded by _

So if I have `John_K_&_E_Scott` I would like to have `John__&__Scott` as I can remove the punctuation. I have tried the below

```
names[, JOINING_ID := gsub("[A-Za-z]_&_[A-Za-z]\\w", "", JOINING_ID)]
```

But this transforms `John_A_&_ BOYS_` in `John__&_ OYS_` which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following regex pattern:

```
_[[:alpha:]]_&_[[:alpha:]]_
```

and replace with `__&__`. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0Me3Ih/1). It won't match strings like `John_A_&_BOYS_` and thus there won't be issues like the one you are having.

Note that `[[:alpha:]]` matches any letter.

R usage:

```
gsub("_[[:alpha:]]_&_[[:alpha:]]_", "__&__", JOINING_ID)
```

Or, if you only expect 1 match per string, use `sub`:

```
sub("_[[:alpha:]]_&_[[:alpha:]]_", "__&__", JOINING_ID)
```